# How to change the colour of a row in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the background colour of alternating rows in a Bootstrap 3 grid. I thought that I could create some CSS and add it to the class in the div but the colour doesn't change.

Here's my CSS:

```
.row-buffer {
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

.row-even {
background-color:#76A0D3;
}
.row-odd {
background-color:#BDE3FB;
}
```

And my row is being defined like so:

```
<div class="row row-buffer row-even">
```

or:

```
<div class="row row-buffer row-odd">
```

The row-buffer is working perfectly but the row-even and row-odd don't seem to be making any difference? (My rows are being defined within a container.)

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without being able to see your exact situation I'm going to guess that you are having a problem due to selector specificity. If bootstrap has a more specific selector than just .class, then your rule will never override it. You either need to match or be more specific in your selector than bootstrap.

An easy way to typically gain a lot of specificity is to add an id to your selectors like :

```
#myrows .row-even {
    background-color:#76A0D3;
}
#myrows .row-odd {
    background-color:#BDE3FB;
}
```

I created a small example of how specificity can cause problems:
http://jsfiddle.net/path411/JyUy2/

Comment: or maybe just even .row.row-even and .row.row-odd. Might want to clear the rows as well though.

Answer (score 6):

These are the specific selectors you can override to change the color of odd rows in Bootstrap:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, 
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
    background-color: #your-color;
}
```

Answer (score -9):

I assume you are trying to create different background styles/colors for alternating rows in a table.

The simplest way is to just add a self enclosing tag

```
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="danger" />
```

inside your table before the data.In a gridview control in asp.net just place this after the asp

gridview tag and before the columns tag.

You will immediately see the effect since Bootstrap has this predefined.

I hope my answer will help somebody in the future.

Cheers !

Comment: There is already a semantic tag <li> that you can style as needed. You should avoid adding extra divs just to hang css off of when possible.